# Calculate the integral of $\sqrt{36\sin^2(2t)+6\cos^2(t)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

During an arc length calculation I reached the following integral and I am having hard time calculating it:
$$\int\sqrt{36\sin^2(2t)+6\cos^2(t)}\,dt=\sqrt{6}\int\cos t \sqrt{24\sin^2(t)+1}\;dt$$

Where $t\in\left[{-\pi}/{2},{\pi}/{2}\right]$

I tried several techniques but couldn't manage to proceed that much.

Some hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry ! I was typing and the post changed twice.

Comment: What curve are you trying to find the arclength of?

Comment: Now the equation in title and body do not match !

Comment: My curve in parametric representation is $x=3\cos 2t$ and $y=\sqrt{6}\sin t$, And the arc length that I need to calculate is from $t=-\pi/2$ to $t=\pi/2$

Comment: I suggest using $\sqrt{24}\sin t =u$ and see what you get

Comment: @Saita So you're calcualting the arclength of a parabolic segment. There are much easier ways to do this than in the representation you have chosen.

Comment: @Chinny84 Thanks for the hint, It worked.

Comment: @Saita calculate it by means of the change of variables method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos t\sqrt{24\sin^2 t+1}dt\underset{u=\sin(t)}{=}\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{24u^2+1}du\underset{y=\sqrt{24}u}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{24}}\int_{-\sqrt{24}}^{\sqrt{24}}\sqrt{y^2+1}dy$$

Then you pose $y=\text{sinh}(v)$, you use the identity $\cosh^2(x)=1+\sinh^2(x)$ and you conclue.

Comment: $du=\cos t~dt$.

Comment: @Lucian: Thanks, I correct it.

Comment: @idm Thanks for the answer.